# access #text property of XMLAttribute in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath, xml-attribute

I have an xml document formated like this:

```
<root>
<obj>
   <indexlist>
      <index name="NUMD" value="val1" />
      <index name="DATE" value="val2" />
   </indexlist>
</obj>
</root>
```

now I'd like to change the value attribute of the index element where name is set to "DATE". I get the attribute like this:

```
$attr = $xml.selectnodes("//obj/indexlist/index[@name='DATE']/@value")
```

I can view the value by typing this:

```
$attr.'#text'
```

but I can't change it:

```
$attr.'#text' = 'foo'
The property '#text' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:1 char:1
+ $n.'#text' = 'foo'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

**how do I change the value of an XMLAttribute?**

---

I'd also like to stick with XPath returning the attribute directly if that's possible because the end-user of that script will define the elements and attributes to change in a config file using XPath.
While using XPath for the attributes as well the user can simply provide the attribute to change and the future-value with just two arguments: the XPath and the value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Besides `#text`, you can also access `XmlAttribute`'s value via `Value` property :

```
$attr = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//obj/indexlist/index[@name='DATE']/@value")

#print old value
$attr.Value

#update attribute value 
$attr.Value = "new value"

#print new value
$attr.Value
```

Note that `Value` in `$attr.Value` is property name of `XmlAttribute`. It doesn't affected by the fact that the attribute in your XML named `value`.

Comment: actually, the problem was that i used `selectnodes` instead of `selectsinglenode` like you did. when i just echo'd my `$attr` powershell would show me the value of `#text` every time and also would say the returned type is a XmlAttribute if i did a `$attr | gm`. but in fact, the returned type seems to be an arrary or collection which - of course - has no `value` property. using my approach with `$attr[0].value` instead of `$attr.value` also works, but it was your answer and use of `selectsinglenode` that led me into the right direction ;) thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't select the attribute, select the node. The attributes of the node will be represented as properties and can be modified as such:

```psh
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//obj/indexlist/index[@name='DATE']")
$node.value = 'foo'
```

Use a loop if you need to modify several nodes:

```psh
$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("//obj/indexlist/index[@name='DATE']")
foreach ($node in $nodes) {
  $node.value = 'foo'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could also treat the XMl as a text file and have the namespace declarations removed using SED or such.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  It's debatable if this is an answer or a comment; see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags for how some folks at SO think about parsing XML with regex :|

Comment: Yep, more a comment than an answer because it's not even offering a solution but a mere idea. Thanks for your input though.